# How to redirect a domain AND any subdirectory to a new domain?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

So I'm building a new site and everything at the old site is going to be scrapped - including the domain structure, and domain name. I currently have a redirect rule in my .htaccess setup to redirect http://jagdesignideas.com to http://jag.is as such:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?jagdesignideas.com
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ "http://jag.is" [R=301,L]
```

But the trouble is if a user follows a link from elsewhere on the intarwebz to http://jagdesignideas.com/about, for example, that does not redirect to http://jag.is as I would like. Instead it brings up the 404 page from the jagdesignideas.com domain.

How to I get all substrings of jagdesignideas.com domain to endup at the new redirect?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not trying to match pages on the old site to the new site, only do a mass redirect of jagdesignideas.com and anything there just to point at the jag.is domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isse us what you are matching in your RewriteRule: `^(/)?$` matches the root slash or nothing, which means you are only rewriting calls to your domain root. You need to capture all path components instead, using `^.*$`, which matches anything after the domain root, or nothing. This will redirect any call to your old domain, with or without a path, to the root of your new domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?jagdesignideas\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://jag.is [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect your path structure to an identical one on your new server, this will do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://jag.is/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Starting from there, you can basically do any kind of redirect to map old to new path structures – see the [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) reference.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't exactly do what I'm looking for. That still maps any page on the old site to the identical URL at the new site. Since I'm not going to have the same site structure, I simply want all pages at the old site to map to the root of the new site.

Comment: @JAG2007: just remove the `/$1` part in the redirect pattern.